# Can't output ArrayList that uses two objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to take in someones first name and last name, and then take those two `Strings` and put them into one `ArrayList` together.

I am able to take in the two `Strings`, but the problem is I can't output them.

I have two classes as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TakeInName {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Names> studentNames = new ArrayList<Names>();
        Names newName = new Names();

        newName.firstName = scan.nextLine();
        newName.lastName = scan.nextLine();

        studentNames.add(newName);

        Names item = studentNames.get(0);

        System.out.print(item);

    }
}
```

and second:

```
public class Names {
    String lastName;
    String firstName;
}
```

I am not even sure if I made this second class right to be able to do anything with it? Maybe that is my problem?

When I run this code the output I get is:
`Names@5c647e05`

Maybe that is the memory position?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the names you have to do

```
System.out.print(item.firstName+" "+item.lastName);
```

because you are fetching the `Names` object .The string(`Names@5c647e05`) you get is expected.Its the string representation of object where `Name` is the class ,`@` character which joins the string, and `5c647e05` some hash code

Answer to the comment.

The code would be

```
Names newName1=new Names();
newName1.firstName = scan.nextLine();
newName1.lastName = scan.nextLine();
studentNames.add(newName1);

Names newName2=new Names();                //create new object for new name
newName2.firstName = scan.nextLine();
newName2.lastName = scan.nextLine();
studentNames.add(newName2);
Names item = studentNames.get(0);
System.out.print(item.firstName + " " + item.lastName);
Names item1 = studentNames.get(1);
System.out.print(item1.firstName + " " + item1.lastName);
```

Comment: What does being in a list have to do with anything?

Comment: @azurefrog because OP fetching the object from list  I was referring to that

Comment: Now I may be doing this wrong but I just quickly made it so I could add a second full name to the array list like so:
               ' newName.firstName = scan.nextLine();
  newName.lastName = scan.nextLine();
  studentNames.add(newName);
  
  newName.firstName = scan.nextLine();
  newName.lastName = scan.nextLine();
  studentNames.add(newName); '

output like this:

  ' Names item = studentNames.get(0);
  System.out.print(item.firstName + " " + item.lastName);
  Names item1 = studentNames.get(1);
  System.out.print(item1.firstName + " " + item1.lastName); '

it only outputs the second name.

Comment: @AndréFecteau create a new object for the second set of names because when you do `newName.firstName = scan.nextLine(); ` fot the second set of name it changes the previous object properties to that.Check my edits

Comment: @singhakash oh, that is simple, thanks! now If I was to make this something that the user could perpetually keep entering names into until they are done would I need to create a new object every time or is there an easier way than that?

Comment: @AndréFecteau just place you code in a loop and every time ask user if the user want to continue(say inputs are yes or no).If user enters `yes` then repeat the set of code create object, set the names, add to list and if user enters `no` breaks the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can also override toString function in Names class like:

```
public String toString(){
    return lastName + "  " + firstName;
}
```

which is the best option for printing object values as a String

Comment: this code need to be in `Names` class as I mentioned before